# "Смореть" вместо смотреть — неправильное произношение или новая норма?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Замечаю, что на моем любимом радио "Маяк" ведущие и их гости (люди в большинстве своем не просто грамотные, но часто высокообразованные) постоянно произносят "сморю", "посмореть", "несморя  на", пропуская звук "т". Этот звук не относится к интервокальным, легко выпадающим в устной речи (скажешь - скаэшь, будем - буэм). Да и обсуждаемые темы не располагают к просторечию: в студии беседуют о политике, о науке, об искусстве - но продолжают при этом "смореть". Может, это уже норма для разговорной речи москвичей? Всё-таки центральное радио как-никак.

Добавлю, что это особенность речи преимущественно мужчин, а не женщин. А между прочим, во времена моего детства именно мальчики произносили нарочито грубым голосом "Смори!" и ещё "Харэ!"(с ударением на "э", это означало "хватит").

Comment: Не слышал такого. А можно сие где-нибудь в записи услышать?

Comment: Это ужасно. Никакие нормы такого не позволяют.

Comment: Андрей Волос. Недвижимость (2000) // «Новый Мир», 2001   [омонимия снята] Все примеры
Шешнадцать? Смори, давай так: если сёння засылаете десятку, за пятнашку отдадим. Нам чисто мазы нету досуха выжимать. Нам червончик свой отбить― и гуляй. [Андрей Волос. Недвижимость (2000) // «Новый Мир», 2001] [омонимия снята] ←…→
Сергей Каледин. Записки гробокопателя (1987-1999)   [омонимия не снята] Все примеры
Вита вскинула голову. ― Ты смори, глупостей не напори! Она тебе устроит веселую жизнь. Шальная баба! [Сергей Каледин. Записки гробокопателя (1987-1999)] [омонимия не снята] ←…→